# scp can't resolve numeric hostname

Tags: ssh, scp

I tried to use scp as follows:

```
% scp user@10.10.4.12:file .
```

I get:

```
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host 10.10.6.11, user fablab-admin, command scp -v -f /etc/iptables/ssh-rules
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1g 7 Apr 2014
ssh: Could not resolve hostname 10.10.4.12: Bad address
```

I can successfully use ssh to log into that same numeric address:

```
% ssh user@10.10.4.12
```

So, I'm not sure what's going wrong.

Any ideas?

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Can you show us the exact `scp` command line you're using?

Comment: % scp -vvvv  fablab-admin@10.10.6.11:/etc/iptables/ssh-rules .
    Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host 10.10.6.11, user fablab-admin, command scp -v -f /etc/iptables/ssh-rules
    OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1g 7 Apr 2014
    ssh: Could not resolve hostname 10.10.6.11: Bad address

Comment: % scp -vvvv  fablab-admin@10.10.6.11:/etc/iptables/ssh-rules .<br/>
    Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host 10.10.6.11, user fablab-admin, command scp -v -f /etc/iptables/ssh-rules<br/>
    OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1g 7 Apr 2014<br/>
    ssh: Could not resolve hostname 10.10.6.11: Bad address<br/>I give up. I read the page on Comment formatting, but I can't get the markup to work